# Why does this function give an undefined method error but runs using byebug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, erb

This code gives me the following error:

> undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass

```
  def show_username(shipment)
    userid = shipment.logs.last.user_id
    User.find(userid).name
  end
```

However, if I insert a `byebug` I can run the code and access all the variables and methods without any errors.

Using `byebug` I get the following responses:

```
(byebug) shipment.logs.last
Log Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE "logs"."shipment_id" = $1 ORDER BY "logs"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["shipment_id", 95], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    #<Log id: 87, activity: "Shipment updated", created_at: "2017-08-28 15:19:07", updated_at: "2017-08-28 15:19:07", shipment_id: 95, user_id: 3>

(byebug) shipment.logs.last.user_id
  Log Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE "logs"."shipment_id" = $1 ORDER BY "logs"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["shipment_id", 95], ["LIMIT", 1]]
3
```

Comment: what is the value of shipment.logs.last?

Comment: Going to assume we are in Rails here due to the tag. Do you have an association setup between shipment and users? Also, have you hopped into `rails console` and validated `shipment.logs.last.user_id` returns as expected? If you had associations created properly I'd assume you could do something like `shipment.logs.last.user.name` instead.

Comment: I updated the question. The associations work when I use `byebug`. I don't understand why there is an error when the code runs naturally.

Comment: Any chance you are running this code in two different environments? Once where shipment.logs.last exist and one where it doesn't. If you have associations sets, you don't need the `User.find(user_id)` bit (also remember to use underscore to separate words: `user_id`, to follow Ruby's best practices), simply doing `shipment.logs.last.user.name` will work.

Comment: You might have `shipments` where there are no related log records. Hop into rails console and try something like `Shipment.all.select { |s| s.logs.empty? }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shipment.logs.last` must be `nil`! Perhaps you are calling the method many times and your `byebug` is stopping in a context that `shipment.logs.last` is not `nil`...

Try to debug giving a condition to call `byebug`:

```
def show_username(shipment)
  byebug unless shipment.logs.last
  userid = shipment.logs.last.user_id
  User.find(userid).name
end
```

Comment: That was the problem! When I stepped through the byebug frame by frame there were eventually shipments that didn't have logs. I will validate that logs exist.